# Link to users profile

Tags: php, mysql

I've a list with all of my users in it and when you click on their name it should show the users profile. But with my query I just see my profile. No matter which user I choose on my list.

so the list is in my admin.php file because just admins can see the user list.

```
<ul>
 <?php
 include_once('connect.php');

 $pdostatement = $conn->prepare( 
   'SELECT 
     f_name 
   FROM 
     tbl_user 
   WHERE 
     id = :user_id' );
 $pdostatement->execute(array(
   'user_id'  => $_SESSION["user_id"]
 ));

 $list        =  $pdostatement->fetchAll();
 $value_fname = $list;


 foreach($value_fname as $row) {
 echo '<li value="'.$row['f_name'].'"><a href="index.php?page=profile" >'.$row['f_name'].'</a></li>';

}

 ?>
</ul>
```

$_SESSION['user_id'] is declared on my login file

```
if ($result[0]["password"] !== md5($_POST['password'].'D6tp'.$_POST['email'])) {
header('Location: /Home/index.php?page=login');
} else {
   $_SESSION['loged_in'] = true;
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result[0]["id"];
   header('Location: /Home');
};
```

And here is a part of my database

```
id  int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
state   varchar(255)
f_name  varchar(255)
```

I appreciate every help!

Comment: Of course you get your own profile, you query for your id. You need to send the user's id (who you want to see) somehow, probably via GET like `index.php?page=profile&id=$row['id']` and then change `_SESSION` to `_GET`

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for your answer

Comment: so I tried it but it doesn't work .. when I do it like you did the id doesnt show up in the url

Answer (score 0):

Your code below contains a where that selects only the current user.

```
$pdostatement = $conn->prepare( 
'SELECT 
   f_name 
 FROM 
   tbl_user 
 WHERE 
   id = :user_id' );
$pdostatement->execute(array(
  'user_id'  => $_SESSION["user_id"]
));
```

To select all users change that code in something like this

```
$pdostatement = $conn->prepare( 
'SELECT 
   f_name 
 FROM 
   tbl_user 
 WHERE 1' );
$pdostatement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

in your database every user have one unique id.

do like this,

```
table1 -> id int, state varchar, f_name varchar
table2 -> id int, f_name, friend
```

then

```
select * from table2 where f_name = :user_id
```